# not all code paths return a value error when i tried to return something

Tags: c#

** why i get this error (not all code paths return a value)
    when i tried to return something in the function how can i solve it 
i need to return values as the following code but i can't do it because of this error can any one help me **

```
public int return_order(string product_name)
{
    FileStream f1 = new FileStream("name.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader r1 = new StreamReader(f1);
    string name = r1.ReadLine();
    r1.Close();
    SqlConnection s = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ShoppingOnline;Integrated Security=True");
    s.Open();
    SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ProductName ='" + product_name + "'", s);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = d.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    dr.Close();
    if (i == 1)
    {
        Form3 f = new Form3();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET Quantity = Quantity + 1 WHERE ProductName= @username ", s);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", product_name);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime startdate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        FileStream f = new FileStream("bill.txt", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f);
        string q = r.ReadToEnd();
        string w = "";

        if (q.Contains(product_name))
        {
            while(r.ReadLine()!="EOO")
            {
                f.Position = 0;
                r.DiscardBufferedData();
                string enddate=r.ReadLine();
                f.Position = 0;
                r.DiscardBufferedData();
                while (r.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);  
                    DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);

                    if ((dt2 - dt.Date).TotalDays < 14)
                    {
                        string temp = r.ReadLine();
                        if (temp == "Customer Name: " + name + "")
                        {
                            string record = r.ReadLine();
                            string[] fields = record.Split('@');
                            if (fields[0] == product_name)
                            {
                                w = fields[1];
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Products(ProductName,Price,Quantity) values('" + product_name + "','" + w + "','" + 1 + "')", s);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                return 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        return -1; 
                    }//late
                }
                r.Close();
            }
        }
        else 
        { 
            return 2; 
        }//wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set a correct indentation of your code you could see that there are numerous if conditions that _if not taken_ could allow this code to exit without returning a value.

Comment: What if `i == 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code by using early returns. And found two undefined paths (see comments).

I have no analyzed this code. Just made mechanical conversions by reversing conditions. (by the way the code needs to be seriously reviewed)

```
public int return_order(string product_name)
{
    FileStream f1 = new FileStream("name.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader r1 = new StreamReader(f1);
    string name = r1.ReadLine();
    r1.Close();
    SqlConnection s = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ShoppingOnline;Integrated Security=True");
    s.Open();
    SqlCommand d = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ProductName ='" + product_name + "'", s);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = d.ExecuteReader();
    int i = 0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    dr.Close();
    if (i == 1)
    {
        Form3 f = new Form3();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET Quantity = Quantity + 1 WHERE ProductName= @username ", s);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", product_name);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return 555; //you had no value!!!
    }

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime startdate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
    FileStream f = new FileStream("bill.txt", FileMode.Open);
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f);
    string q = r.ReadToEnd();
    string w = "";

    if (!q.Contains(product_name))
        return 2; //wrong

    while (r.ReadLine() != "EOO")
    {
        f.Position = 0;
        r.DiscardBufferedData();
        string enddate = r.ReadLine();
        f.Position = 0;
        r.DiscardBufferedData();
        while (r.Peek() != -1)
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);
            DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);

            if ((dt2 - dt.Date).TotalDays >= 14)
                return -1; //late

            string temp = r.ReadLine();
            if (temp == "Customer Name: " + name + "")
            {
                string record = r.ReadLine();
                string[] fields = record.Split('@');
                if (fields[0] == product_name)
                {
                    w = fields[1];
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Products(ProductName,Price,Quantity) values('" + product_name + "','" + w + "','" + 1 + "')", s);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        r.Close();
    }
    return 555; //some default value (you had no value!!!)
}
```